# Are Zero Degree polynomials Considered monics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

DO zero degree polynomials that is constant polynomials considered monic polynomials? Example F(x)=16   Does it Matter the Field or the Integral region where i take the coeficients from?Sorry if the question is stupid .BUt i saw that the Set of monic polynomials is closed under multyplication.So if the constant polynomials where inside the set then i would get a non monic polynomial

Comment: No. Only the unit is monic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A monic polynomial is any polynomial $f(x)=a_n x^n + a_{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x^1 + a_0 x^0$ such that $a_n=1$. Therefore, a monic polynomial of degree zero is of the form $f(x) = a_0$ where $a_n = a_0 = 1$ as $n=0$ so they may only take the form $f(x) = 1$.